# update to OpenGL 3.2 intel celeron archLinux

Tags: linux, opengl, graphics, intel

I have a noteBook with an arch Linux installed on it.

I would like to start some OpenGL programming but it seems that OpenGL 3.2 is not supported.

I don't have dedicated GPU.
My processor is an intel celeron N2830
http://ark.intel.com/products/81071/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N2830-1M-Cache-up-to-2_41-GHz

So is there a driver that can give me OpenGL 3.2 ? or It is a hardware limition problem ?

```
$glxinfo | grep "OpenGl"
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Bay Trail
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.6.4
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.6.4
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 10.6.4
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have OpenGL 3.3 support:

> ```
> OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.6.4
> OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
> ```

The open source drivers from mesa (which are the only ones for intel GPUs on linux) support OpenGL >= 3.2 only as *core* profiles (which is the only profile required to be implemented, according to the OpenGL spec). For legacy profiles, mesa is limited to 3.0 or 3.1. But if you are starting with OpenGL right now, you really shouldn't even care about the sole existence of legacy GL or compatibility profiles, so everything is fine.